# Computing determinant of the matrix $C$

Tags: determinant

Let

$$C=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \cdots &0 & -c_0 \\ 
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0& -c_1 \\
0& 1 & \cdots & 0& -c_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & & & \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -c_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then why

$$\det (zI-C) = c_0 + c_1 z + \ldots + c_{n-1}z^{n-1} + z^n$$

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) in the last column.